# How to use the where clause where the values in a columns are not explicit in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a restriction column that contains both gender and age range. 
I could use the WHERE clause for "MEN" and "WOMEN" to return only the rows that satisfy the condition. But this restriction column also contains the age range like "Teenager", "Adult" and "Senior" so I'm not sure how to specify the WHERE clause. Sometimes the gender and age range restrictions are unspecified so for example for a list of row that satisfies the condition "MEN", all unspecified columns should also be returned.

Example of the column:

> Restriction:
>
> -MEN
>
> -WOMEN
>
> -WOMEN/Teenager
>
> -Anyone
>
> -Men/Senior
>
> -Senior

[restriction columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBWhC.png)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: When you got abstract things like "Teenager" you don't have any gender information the same way you don't have information of age if all your data provides is gender information. This shows why data sanitazion and separation is important. There's no way to do this job (right) by lack of data (and data modeling)

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to use `LIKE` operator. The following are some examples for the `WHERE` clause:

1. To get all Men fields : `WHERE YOUR_CLM  LIKE 'MEN%'`
2. To get all Adults fields : `WHERE YOUR_CLM  LIKE '%Adult'`
3. To get all non-Senior Women fields : `WHERE YOUR_CLM NOT LIKE '%Senior' AND YOUR_CLM LIKE 'WOMEN%'`

**NOTE**: if you are allowed to make changes on the database schema, then I would recommend to split this column into two columns one for age and the other for gender, each column is represented by an ID which represents a value stored in a list-of-values table (ex; `GendersLOV` table, `AgeLOV` table)